refrescar libreria fullcalendar
estoy usando la vercion de FullCalendar v5.3.2 la estoy cargando los eventos mediante codigo php


 events: [
    <?php 
            foreach ($data['calendario'] as $descripcion) {
            echo "{title:'".$descripcion['descripcion']."',start:'".$descripcion['fecha']."'},";
            }
        ?>
    ]



Lo que quiero es que al terminar de guarda un evento se me recarge el calendario, este es mi codigo para guardar los datos en la bd.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    
    if(document.querySelector("#formCalendario")){
        let formCalendario = document.querySelector("#formCalendario");
        formCalendario.onsubmit = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let strFecha = document.querySelector('#txtFecha').value;
            let strDescripcion = document.querySelector('#txtDescripcion').value;

            if(strFecha == '' || strDescripcion == '')
            {
                swal.fire("Atención", "Todos los campos son obligatorios." , "error");
                return false;
            }

            let elementsValid = document.getElementsByClassName("valid");
            for (let i = 0; i < elementsValid.length; i++) { 
                if(elementsValid[i].classList.contains('is-invalid')) { 
                    swal.fire("Atención", "Por favor verifique los campos en rojo." , "error");
                    return false;
                } 
            } 
            let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            
            
            let ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Calendario/setCalendario'; 
            let formData = new FormData(formCalendario);
            request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
            request.send(formData);
            
            request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                    let objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    if(objData.status)
                    {
                        $('#calendarioModal').modal("hide");
                        formCalendario.reset();
                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');
                        swal.fire("Recordatorio", objData.msg ,"success");
                    }else{
                        swal.fire("Error", objData.msg , "error");
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }



supuesta mente con $("#calendar").fullCalendar('render'); deberia recargarse pero no me anda. Este archivo llama a una funcion para almacenar los datos y si todo esta correcto deberia de mostrar el mensaje en patalla Los datos fueron guardados cosa que lo hace y luego recargar el calendario asi se muestra actualizado. Pero esa parte no anda.

Es probable que me confunda, pero no parece que recarges los events en ninguna parte, tan solo le dices al fullCalendar que renderize de nuevo, seguramente sobre los events anteriores.

Perdon es verdad pero use esta calendar.refetchEvents(); y tampoco anda

¿Y si primero haces un calendar.getEventSources() y despues el refetch?
